# Flowfield density conversion

Tags: algorithm, grid

I'm trying to implement flowfield navigation, as described in http://grail.cs.washington.edu/projects/crowd-flows/
but I can't understand how the Density Function in Figure 4 of the paper is supposed to handle unit radius.

Has anyone ever implemented that and can provide more information?

This is the part in question:

[image]

Their algorithm seems to be using only 4 cells, pointing to the lower left of the unit, so is this some kind of kernel that needs to be applied multiple times?

Thanks.

Comment: Could not add more relevant tags because of reputation level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a "kernel that needs to be applied multiple times".  You just apply the formulas as written, once.

It's kind of a weird rule, though, and not very clearly described.  Let me try to clarify it a bit:

- First, find the four cells whose shared corner is closest to the unit.  The unit will contribute a non-zero amount of density only to those cells.  Call those cells A, B, C and D as in figure 4(b).
- Let Δx and Δy be the horizontal and vertical distance of the unit from the center of cell A, measured in units of one cell width/height.
- Let ρ<sub>A</sub> = min(1−Δx, 1−Δy)<sup>λ</sup>,  ρ<sub>B</sub> = min(Δx, 1−Δy)<sup>λ</sup>,  ρ<sub>C</sub> = min(Δx, Δy)<sup>λ</sup> and  ρ<sub>D</sub> = min(1−Δx, Δy)<sup>λ</sup>, as described in the paper.
- Let the unit contribute ρ<sub>A</sub> density to cell A, ρ<sub>B</sub> density to cell B, ρ<sub>C</sub> density to cell C and ρ<sub>D</sub> density to cell D.

As I said, the rule is kind of weird, and I have no obvious geometric interpretation to offer for it.  It does, however, satisfy the expected properties that:

- When the unit is exactly in the middle of any cell X, then (regardless of which of A, B, C or D we choose X to be) it contributes 1<sup>λ</sup> = 1 unit of density to cell X and 0 units of density to any other cell.
- When the unit is exactly at the corner of four cells, it contributes (1/2)<sup>λ</sup> units of density to each of the four cells (and nothing to any other cell, by definition).

However, note that, using this rule, the total amount of density contributed by a unit to all cells is *not* constant, not even if λ = 1.  In particular, when the unit is exactly at the midpoint of the edge between two cells, it contributes (1/2)<sup>λ</sup> units of density to those *two* cells, and nothing to any other cell.  Thus, calling the resulting value a "density" seems a bit misleading.

---

Edit: Another way of writing the formulas for ρ<sub>A</sub>, ρ<sub>B</sub>, ρ<sub>C</sub> and ρ<sub>D</sub>, which may make the symmetry of the definitions more apparent, is to define d<sub>X</sub> = max( |x − x<sub>X</sub>|, |y − y<sub>X</sub>| ) as the [chessboard distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance) of the unit at (x, y) from the center of the cell X at (x<sub>X</sub>, y<sub>X</sub>), measured in cell widths/heights.
Then, for any cell X,

- ρ<sub>X</sub> = 0 if d<sub>X</sub> ≥ 1, and
- ρ<sub>X</sub> = (1 − d<sub>X</sub>)<sup>λ</sup> otherwise.

Comment: I don't understand the reason why the bottom left cells adjacent to the one the agent is in should receive density value while the top right ones should not.

Comment: @sharvey: Because in the picture, the agent is below and to the left of the center of the cell it is in.

Comment: Ah, it makes sense. But just to be clear, the radius of the unit has nothing to do with the density calculation, right?

Comment: Right, there doesn't appear to be any "radius" in the formulas you quoted that could enter into those calculations.

Comment: I'm not closer to actually implementing it, but thanks for the answer. Guess I'll read the paper again.